# NullPointerException when sendBillingRequest() function is called in GetPurchaseInformation class about inapp

Tags: android

I'm in trouble by the following log.

I've tested like this.

1. Purchased inapp item in my android application
2. Canceled the purchased item in Google Checkout web page.
3. At this time, `run()` function of `GetPurhcaseInformation` class is called in my running android application.
4. In this `run()` function, `mService.sendBillingRequest(request)` is called.
5. The following exception log is displayed immediately.

But, Dungeons sample works very well.
My application uses some other broadcast receiver. 
I blocked these receiver, but the problem is occurred yet.

I found the link equals to my problem in web. But the bug wasn't be accepted and no answer.
http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=18

I'd like to know the code in MarketBillingService.java:661.

Any Ideas?

```
10-06 18:26:52.029: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8080): Shutting down VM
10-06 18:26:52.029: WARN/dalvikvm(8080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.MarketBillingService$BillingNotifier.showStatusBarNotifications(MarketBillingService.java:661)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.MarketBillingService$Stub$1.onResponse(MarketBillingService.java:409)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.MarketBillingService$Stub$1.onResponse(MarketBillingService.java:401)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.google.android.vending.remoting.api.VendingRequest.deliverResponse(VendingRequest.java:144)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.google.android.vending.remoting.api.VendingRequest.deliverResponse(VendingRequest.java:42)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:88)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 18:26:52.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

In file `ExecutorDelivery.java` at `line 88`, having problem that you're trying to use some `NULL` objects in this method.

Comment: Thank you. But where can i see the code or description of this file? I can't this file in android source code.

Comment: Sorry, I found a reason. my app is launcher and if i remove <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/> and add <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>, this exception isn't be occurred. Dungeon sample is not launcher too. And then, Why this exception is occurred in launcher app? Hmm...